# Anderson-Darling normality test on all columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, distribution, normal-distribution

I want to apply Anderson-Darling normality test to all columns on a big data frame in R.

To apply the test on one columns, I'm using:

```
library(nortest)
ad.test(df$col1)
```

I tried the following to apply it to every single column, but it didn't work:

```
ad.test(df)  
*Error in [.data.frame(x, complete.cases(x)) :    undefined columns selected*

normality_check = lapply(df,ad.test) 
*Error in if (AA < 0.2) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed*
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: `lapply(df, ad.test)` should work, unless your `df` contains columns for which the test produces "missing values" error.

Comment: Thanks.....you are right. I filtered the columns and it worked.