# How to do Anderson Darling test for all the columns

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

When I apply Anderson-Darling test on my dataset using `lapply`, I got results only for few columns. What would be the reason? Is there any solution?

I tried:

```
lapply(df4, ad.test)
```

or

```
apply(df,2,ad.test)
```

For both of these I got the same results, but like I said not for all of the columns.

Here's a link to a related question: [Anderson-Darling normality test on all columns of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368682/anderson-darling-normality-test-on-all-columns-of-a-dataframe/75247184)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data. Taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can be helpful as well.

Comment: The comments under the the question you link suggest that `ad.test` will only work on numeric columns without missing values. Have you checked that all your columns are numeric? Have you checked that they don't have missing values?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.